Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
It appeared on its own a couple of times, although the tests were running before that. Now, having created a new project and written the first test, the error has not disappeared.
I created unitTest for my VisualTransformation logic(compose). This logic locating is in a different class, and it is not in VisualTransformation. And I tried to run a test for this class and I get this stacktrace error:
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 15.
java.io.IOException: ���� �������� ������
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.writeBuffer(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:98)
at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:85)
at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

> Task :textwatcher:testReleaseUnitTest FAILED
> Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
> Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 15' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 15' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:442)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.onProcessStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:146)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.access$000(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:43)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess$1.executionFinished(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:99)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:268)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:170)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:148)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy141.executionFinished(Unknown Source)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:221)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.finished(DefaultExecHandle.java:381)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.completed(ExecHandleRunner.java:134)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.lambda$run$2(ExecHandleRunner.java:97)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:95)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':textwatcher:testReleaseUnitTest'.

> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 14' finished with non-zero exit value 1\

I cant found helpful answer for this. I tried delete .gradle in my project and rebuild also close Android Studio, clear cache and other... Also i updated my gradle to the latest version + update java in my proj to 17
This problem occurs frequently, during some unforeseen periods.
I`m using Android Gradle Plugin - 8.5.0 \ Gradle - 8.8
this is code of my Test - https://pl.kotl.in/nNwZPhaTY

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I found the answer in another stack thread, origin
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
After I removed file.encoding option like below, there was no more problem for me.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
